# VIsual Studio 2010 colour schemes compatible with ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, color-scheme

Are there any colour schemes for **VS 2010** (preferably dark schemes) that include settings for **ReSharper 5.1**?

All attempts at google-fu have failed me.

The one I'm using at the moment messes up when R# tries to highlight a line because the colours are too similar.

I know I could do this myself... and will if I have to. But if there are already some schemes to save me the effort, it would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a dark theme? If so, ping me and I'll send you mine.

Comment: Could you send it to me as well (email in the profile)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Hadi Hariri: Thanx for the email with the two vssettings files. I have to admit that both looked horrible with current line and color identifiers enabled (VS10 + R#5.1). I'm guessing that you don't use those features of R#? Also, see this SO question from a bloke with the same wish as me: http://goo.gl/FzqwO

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this one lately in 2010:

[Visual Studio Settings for the TDD Ninja](http://blog.typemock.com/2010/03/visual-studio-settings-for-tdd-ninja.html)